# suffix array Index out of bounds

Tags: swift

I have an array , when I suffix array and want to select element , I get error: Index out of bounds.
But when I prefix array and select element, It's sucess.

How should I do that I can select after suffix array?

Here is code:

```
let array = [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10]
let suffixArray = array.suffix(5)//[6,7,8,9,10]
let prefixArray = array.prefix(5)//[1,2,3,4,5]
print(suffixArray[2])//Index out of bounds
print(prefixArray[2])//sucess print "3"
```

Comment: Did my answer work for you?

Comment: @IiroAlhonen your and Belyaev's answers are great help for me! Thanks!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem you are having is that with `.suffix` the array does not start with 0. So if you wanted to print the 3rd number in the suffix array, you would have to call `print(suffixArray[7]`.

If you read the description for the return value [here](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swift/array/1687909-suffix). It reads:

> A subsequence terminating at the end of the collection with at most maxLength elements.

And if you read the description to [subsequence](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swift/array/subsequence):

> A collection representing a contiguous subrange of this collection’s elements. The subsequence shares indices with the original collection.

Full example for playground:

```swift
let array = [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10]
let suffixArray = array.suffix(5) // [6,7,8,9,10]
let prefixArray = array.prefix(5) // [1,2,3,4,5]
var newSuffixArray: [Int] = []
for i in suffixArray {
    newSuffixArray.append(i)
}

print(suffixArray[7]) // 8
print(newSuffixArray[2]) // 8
print(prefixArray[2]) // 3
```

Answer (score 0):

Both `prefix` and `suffix` return an `ArraySlice` rather than another `Array`.

Here's an excerpt from the [`ArraySlice` documentation](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swift/arrayslice):

> Unlike `Array` and `ContiguousArray`, the starting index for an
> `ArraySlice` instance isn’t always zero. Slices maintain the same
> indices of the larger array for the same elements, so the starting
> index of a slice depends on how it was created, letting you perform
> index-based operations on either a full array or a slice. Sharing
> indices between collections and their subsequences is an important
> part of the design of Swift’s collection algorithms.

You can see that by looking into the `indices` property of `prefixArray` and `suffixArray`.

Generally you are encouraged to use methods of accessing elements that collections provide instead of assuming values of indices.

Comment: This is correct. If u want to cast ```ArraySlice``` to ```Array```, use ```Array(array.suffix(5))```.

Comment: That will work, but it's less efficient because it implies creating a whole new array, which is not as cheap as a slice. In many cases there are ways to solve a task without ever creating a new array, just using the builtin methods of collections. For example, if I needed a 3rd element from the slice, I'd rather do something like `slice.dropFirst(2).first`. It's faster than creating a new array and way safer than just accessing an element by its raw index.